# round(microtime(true) * 1000) equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, .net

Please help me to create in c# equivalent php 
`round(microtime(true) * 1000)`

Figure should turn out similar to the 1457914762598

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not a code translation service.

Comment: well, the result will be too big for a 32 bit integer anyways if you are going to multiply by 1000. Why don't you just put your requirements into google and see what comes up first?

Comment: `(long)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# your savior is `DateTimeOffset`class.

```
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
```

It will print (as moment of writing):

```
1458062469274
```

Hope this is what are you looking for.